# Android listview item bottom margin not working

Tags: android, margin, expandablelistview

I have an Expandable list view like

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seperator"
    android:divider="#ffededed"
    android:dividerHeight="0.0dip"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:listSelector="#ffededed" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

And the layout for the group item in the list view with

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:padding="@dimen/common_padding" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is both left, right and top margins are working. But i ca't find the bottom margin ? Please help me to figure it out beacause i'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

In default childs of RelativeLayout align in top corner.

Try to set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for your child RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

my work around was to put the listview inside a Linearlayout,

so, change from

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

To

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and problem is solved